# Will my friends receive an explicit notification if I like a photo?

Tags: facebook

I wanted to like all the photos of a girl, but I don't want my friends on Facebook to know I have done that.

Will my friends be notified of these likes explicitly on the first page/main activity when they visit the Facebook website or app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your friends (except those whose photo/status you are liking) will not receive any notification. But all those friends who have marked your profile as first, they will see your almost every activity on their Timeline and those who are following might not see everything, but yes they will also see most of the things on their Timeline.